# The HTTP proxy server may not be supported by PySocks (must be a CONNECT tunnel proxy)

Tags: python, proxy, smtplib, imaplib, pysocks

The main idea is to send email through the proxy server using python **smtplib**.
I had my own HTTP proxy server.
There are no brief talks about this in any community

What I'm tried is:

```
import socks
import smtplib

// Assume that below proxy host and port working, checked with request module
proxy_username = 'XXXX'
proxy_paas = 'YYYY'
proxy_host = '0.0.0.0'
proxy_port = 4444
socks.set_default_proxy(
        socks.PROXY_TYPE_HTTP,
        proxy_host,
        proxy_port,
        username=proxy_username,
        password=proxy_paas
)
socks.wrap_module(smtplib)
smtp = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
print(smtp)
```

Facing Error from **PySocks** like below:

```
raise GeneralProxyError("Socket error", error)
socks.GeneralProxyError: Socket error: 403: Forbidden

[*] Note: The HTTP proxy server may not be supported by PySocks (must be a CONNECT tunnel proxy)
```

Comment: Because SMTP doesn't use HTTP, it can't use a HTTP proxying, it must use `CONNECT` proxying.  The error message is saying the sever gave a 403 (Forbidden) error when it tried to use the CONNECT verb on the server.  Possibly your credentials are incorrect, or your server is configured to only allow CONNECT to port 443 or similar (which is a common configuration)